# How to type character - in LaTeX?

Tags: characters

I need to insert

```
-max_target_seqs 100 -outfmt “6 qseqid sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send evalue bitscore qseq sseq” -task megablast
```

(source https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5863388/#Sec5title )

I want it in italic

```
\textit{-max_target_seqs 100 -outfmt “6 qseqid sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send evalue bitscore qseq sseq” -task megablast}
```

But has error

> ! Missing $ inserted.$ ...ue bitscore qseq sseq” -task
> megablast}

How to fix it?

Comment: The character `_` is used in mathmode. Add a \ in front of each like this: `\textit{-max\_target\_seqs 100 -outfmt ``6 qseqid sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send evalue bitscore qseq sseq'' -task megablast}`

Comment: Try this: `\textit{-max\_target\_seqs 100 -outfmt ``6 qseqid sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send evalue bitscore qseq sseq'' -task megablast}`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved by comment..

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
\emph{-max\_target\_seqs 100 -outfmt ``6 qseqid sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send evalue bitscore qseq sseq'' -task megablast}
```

[image]